# Getting data from MYSQL with SCRAPY then Compare new item price then save mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, scrapy

i have a project in python.

my goal in the project is to compare the prices I have scraped on amazon with the prices in mysql.

if the new price is lower than in mysql, I want to send a message to telegram.

***I have been doing research to solve this problem for days..***

**my database is as follows in the link below**

https://dbfiddle.uk/fbeR9LTE

.

**error mesage is ;**

```
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "C:\hazır\amazon\amzndata\amzndata\pipelines.py", line 57, in process_item
    db_item = self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM amazon.amzurun')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 249, in execute
    self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 862, in handle_unread_result
    raise InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
---------------------------------------->/s?i=computers&rh=n%3A12601904031&fs=true&page=6&qid=1665676056&ref=sr_pg_5
2022-10-13 18:47:36 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Scraper close failure
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from cmath import asin
from multiprocessing import connection
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
import telegram, aiohttp
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import mysql.connector

class SaveMySQLPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password = '88522',
            database = 'amazon'
        )
        self.sleep_time = 1 # Minutes
        self.API_KEY = 'ebfc9e2598058bb3b85e3c5da588046d'  # ScraperAPI Proxies
        #269a80e9214e2388aaa666b7352fc305, ebfc9e2598058bb3b85e3c5da588046d
    
        self.bot_1 = telegram.Bot("1693849140:AAEur4Z4jOI57VbwtIj5QY9nwaGTPdvLNeo") # Bot 1
        
        self.ADMIN_LIST = ["@bbot"]                           # Admin Chat ID
        self.test_group_chat_id  = "@etoien"

        ## Create cursor, used to execute commands
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        ## Create quotes table if none exists
        self.cur.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amzurun (
            id int NOT NULL auto_increment, 
            name text,
            price text,
            asin text,
            date datetime,
            link text,
            stars text,
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )
        """)
    def send_message_to_group(self, chat_id, text):
        while True:
            bot = choice([self.bot_1, self.bot_2, self.bot_3, self.bot_4])
            try : bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text); break
            except Exception as e: time.sleep(1)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        db_item = self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM amazon.amzurun')
        item["asin"] = db_item(asin)
        if item['price'] < db_item['price']:
            text = f"""%{abs(int(((product['price'] - old_price) / old_price) * 100))} Discount\n{product['name']}\n{old_price} TL >> {product['price']} TL\nURL :\n{product['link']}\n"""

            self.send_message_to_group(self.test_group_chat_id, text)
            print(text)
        ## Define insert statement
        self.cur.execute(""" insert into amzurun (name, price, asin, date, link, stars ) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item["name"],
            item["price"],
            item["asin"],
            item["date"],
            item["link"],
            item["stars"]
        ))
        return item

        ## Execute insert of data into database
        self.conn.commit()


    def close_spider(self, spider):

        ## Close cursor & connection to database 
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()


class AmzndataPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

**when I remove this part of the code, it registers the database without any problems.**

```
db_item = self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM amazon.amzurun')
item["asin"] = db_item(asin)
if item['price'] < db_item['price']:
    text = f"""%{abs(int(((product['price'] - old_price) / old_price) * 100))} Discount\n{product['name']}\n{old_price} TL >> {product['price']} TL\nURL :\n{product['link']}\n"""

    self.send_message_to_group(self.test_group_chat_id, text)
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the data from the cursor after the execute statement, also the commit statement needs to happen before the return statement in the `process_items` function.

For Example:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM amazon.amzurun')
        db_item = self.cur.fetchall()
        item["asin"] = db_item(asin)
        if item['price'] < db_item['price']:
            text = f"""%{abs(int(((product['price'] - old_price) / old_price) * 100))} Discount\n{product['name']}\n{old_price} TL >> {product['price']} TL\nURL :\n{product['link']}\n"""

            self.send_message_to_group(self.test_group_chat_id, text)
            print(text)
        ## Define insert statement
        self.cur.execute(""" insert into amzurun (name, price, asin, date, link, stars ) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item["name"],
            item["price"],
            item["asin"],
            item["date"],
            item["link"],
            item["stars"]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
        return item
```

Comment: item["asin"] = db_item(asin)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable   .

| ||     when I run the example code above, it gives this error.